# how to send return(enter button) character through program

Tags: c++, c, windows

how to send return(enter button) character  through program in windows c/c++? I want to send an  external program  "user name" with enter button through pipe but "\n" and "\r" and EOF are not working..

Comment: '\r' is simply a character constant escape sequence for ASCII carriage return. Similarly '\n' is ASCII line-feed. So you cannot simply say that they "don't work" without showing us how you are trying to make them work. It is almost certain that it is your use of them that is not working rather than the character codes themselves - they are just numbers, in what way can a number 'not work'?

Answer (score 1):

If this is conole application, write "\r\n" to its STDIN.

Otherwise, use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this: [CodeProject: C++ SendKeys](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/sendkeys_cpp_Article.aspx) ?

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what do you need, maybe this: "\r\n"?